# performSelector:withObject:afterDelay: - a way to do this to pass something other than an object?

Tags: xcode

I am trying to use this method to show a second modal after a first modal has been dismissed...  The method itself works fine, except that it requires me to pass an object as a parameter and what I really want to do is pass a UIImageControllerSourceType instead.  Is there another method I should be using to do this or is there an easy way to make UIImageControllerSourceType an object?  I feel like this should not be too hard but I have been struggling with it for awhile now...

```
- (void)showModalTwoImageSearchViewControllerWithSourceType:(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType *)sourceType {

if (self.modalViewController) {        
    [self performSelector:@selector(showModalTwoImageSearchViewControllerWithSourceType:)
               withObject:sourceType
               afterDelay:0.1f];
    return;
}
// present second modal view - remembering to deal with cases of camera or photo library
if (sourceType == UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary) {
    //do one thing
}
// lets assume it was UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera
else {
    // do something else
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UIImagePickerControllerSourceType` is ultimately a `NSUInteger` and the method you're trying to do (the performSelector one) only takes Objective C objects in its `withObject` parameter and not C types or pointers.

You can pass `NSUIntegers` by creating a `NSNumber` object and stuffing your integer into that.

To create a `NSNumber` object, you can create one as easily as `NSNumber`'s [`numberWithUnsignedInteger`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumber_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSNumber/numberWithUnsignedInteger%3a) method.

Comment: thanks!  I knew it was a simple answer - just could not find the way to convert the UIImagePickerController into an object.

Answer (score 0):

UIImagePickerControllerSourceType is an enum. the easiest way to use it as an object is to make it an NSNumber:

```
NSNumber *n = [NSNumber numberWithInt:sourceType];
```